# Check when multiple files have dowloaded with PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, cordova

I've been using PhoneGap 2.9.0 (with build) to download files from a website to store on my sdcard on my android device.

I am looking for a solution to download multiple files and check that all of these requests have been completed successfull.

I have been told this is possible with using **[jQuery.Deffered](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/)** but I have yet to use this in any code and I am struggling to get my head round it.

Existing Code works fine in theory but only checks when the last download in my array has downloaded succesfully but sometimes the last download sometimes returns succesfully before others.

**My code is similar to below:**

```
var ft = new FileTransfer();
var online = [
    'http://google.com/img/1.jpg', 
    'http://google.com/img/2.jpg',
    'http://google.com/img/3.jpg'
];
var sdcard = 'file:///storage/sdcard0/';

$.each( online, function(k,v) { 
    ft.download(
        online[k],
        sdcard,
        win,
        fail
    );
}

var win = function(success, counter){
   // check if counter is last element in array

       // redirect user to page if last element
}

var fail = function(error){
  console.log(error);
}
```

Comment: Maybe if you put all your actions in a jquery 'when()' ?

Comment: Hi Jahnux, it would be great if you could show me an example of how this could work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using simon mcondalds solution and didnt use jQuery.deferred

Basically put all the items i had to get from the web in an array when one was succefully retrived, just remove that item from the array and then call the same function again. Eventually the array.length will have

https://gist.github.com/macdonst/3835045

**Example code here:**

```
var remoteFiles = [];

function downloadRemotePDF() {
    var local2User = JSON.parse( localStorage["locallessons"] );
    $.each(local2User, function(key) {
      remoteFiles.push(optionsJSON +   local2User[key].idcountries + '/' + local2User[key].idcurriculum + '/' + local2User[key].idoptions + '/pdf/' + local2User[key].pdfname);
    }

    downloadFile();
}

function downloadFile() {
    // No files left, stop downloading
    if (remoteFiles.length == 0) {
        return;
    }

    var remoteFile = remoteFiles.pop();
    var localFileName = remoteFile.substring(remoteFile.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile(localFileName, {create: true, exclusive: false}, function(fileEntry) {
            var localPath = fileEntry.fullPath;
            if (device.platform === "Android" && localPath.indexOf("file://") === 0) {
                localPath = localPath.substring(7);
            }
            var ft = new FileTransfer();
            ft.download(remoteFile, localPath, function(entry) {
                // Do what you want with successful file downloaded and then 
                // call the method again to get the next file
                downloadFile();
            }, fail);
        }, fail);
    }, fail); 
}
```

Comment: I wanted to show a message File X of X and was looking at OnProgress Event, and did not want to use Promises. Your solution is elegant, I modified it to pass the file# being download. Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an exemple of jquery when. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

A simple code (not the yours, to explain 'when')

Here is a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/v34ra/

And a simple code with when().done() :

```
$('button').on('click', function(){  

    $.when(

        $('div').each( function(){
            $(this).html(  $(this).attr('attriba')  );
        }  )

    ).done( function(){alert('fin');} );

});
```